# I want to isolate a column which might be contains a combination of string and spaces or might has nothing using regexp or any other command in tcl

Tags: regex, split, tcl

I have a file with the following format:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0              4      26    Future Software Ltd, India
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0              4      27    Future Linux Router Ver 1.0
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0              4      21    FutureSoftware, India
1.3.6.1.4.1.2076.50.3.1.2.1    4       6    NETMAN
1.3.6.1.4.1.2076.50.3.1.2.2    4       6    PUBLIC
1.3.6.1.2.1.26.5.1.1.10.1.1    4       1     
1.3.6.1.2.1.26.5.1.1.10.2.1    4       1     
1.3.6.1.2.1.26.5.1.1.10.3.1    4       1     
1.3.6.1.2.1.26.5.1.1.10.4.1    4       1    
1.3.6.1.4.1.2076.63.4.1.1.3.1  4       1    >
1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.4.3.1.1.1   4       0
```

the 3rd column represents the number of the of characters, white spaces, dots etc which are present in 4th column.
So the actual represention of the previous file is :

[image]

till the 3rd line I successfully use the following regexp:
regexp {^\S+.\d+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)} $line -> secondcolumn thirdcolumn

can you please help me how to isolate also the 4th column in order to include all the above cases (for example in case the 3rd is 1 a white space has been encountered or a special character)?

[image]

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, your columns are separated by a single tab. In that case you can easily get the fields using `split $line \t`.

Answer (score 2):

If simply splitting the lines on a tab does not suffice, I would use [`scan`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/scan.html) to get the first three fields, then use the length to get that amount of characters from the end of the line:

```
set f [open $file]
while {[gets $f line] != -1} {
    if {[scan $line {%s %d %d} oid unknown cnt] == 3} {
        set str [string range $line [expr {[string length $line] - $cnt}] end]
        puts "{$str}"
    }
}
close $f
```

I output the string inside {} to show the spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer it works!!!. One more question please, if I want to calculate the length from the beginning of the line till just before the 4th column? please see the last picture in my post.

Comment: That's pretty much what `expr {[string length $line] - $cnt}` does. Although maybe you need to subtract one to get the character before the 4th column. If that's not what you're asking (your last picture seems to include the 4th column when it's just a space), you may be interested in the %n conversion specifier of the `scan` command: `scan $line {%s %d %d %n} oid unknown cnt pos`